# Oracle How to sum up multiple count fields

Tags: oracle, count, sum

i have this select statement:

```
SELECT 1 AS SoftField, 
       count(form_ref) as Asset
 from risk_register 
where risk_category = 'fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1' 
  and system_type = 'AR'
UNION
SELECT 2 AS SoftField,
       count(form_ref)as Operational
from risk_register 
where risk_category = '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e' 
  and system_type = 'AR'
```

The output:

```
Softfield   Asset 
---------   -----
1           1180
2           2927
```

How can i sum up the Asset to be like this:

```
Softfield   Asset 
---------   -----
1           1180
2           2927
Total       4107
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`group by rollup`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#d424000e4813) to generate a 'superaggregate' row:

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with risk_register (system_type, risk_category, form_ref) as (
  select 'AR', 'fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1', 'x'
  from dual connect by level <= 1180
  union all
  select 'AR', '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e', 'x'
  from dual connect by level <= 2927
)
-- actual query
select case risk_category when 'fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1' then '1'
                          when '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e' then '2'
                          else 'Total' end as softfield,
count(form_ref) as asset
from risk_register
where risk_category in ('fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1',
                        '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e')
and system_type = 'AR'
group by rollup(risk_category)
order by softfield;

SOFTFIELD      ASSET
--------- ----------
1               1180
2               2927
Total           4107
```

This is ordering by a string field which is (kind of) OK with only these values, but if you had more than 9 then it would get a little weird and you'd need to make that a little bit more complicated.

---

@NickKrasnov linked to a simplified version on a comment, which puts the 'softfield' in alphabetic order of category. Your original query has that matching the order you provided the values to search for. It isn't clear if that matters, as the softfield value seems a bit arbitrary anyway. Another way to keep your original order, without repeating the values, is to use a collection (keeping Nick's use of `grouping()`):

```
select case when grouping(coll.risk_category) = 1 then 'Total' 
            else to_char(max(coll.rn)) end as softfield,
  count(rr.form_ref) as asset
from (
  select rownum as rn, column_value as risk_category
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1',
                                  '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e'))
) coll
join risk_register rr
on rr.risk_category = coll.risk_category
where system_type = 'AR'
group by rollup(coll.risk_category)
order by grouping(coll.risk_category), max(coll.rn);
```

If the order doesn't matter, or if you want to see the actual categories that's even simpler again:

```
select case when grouping(risk_category) = 1 then 'Total' 
            else risk_category end as softfield,
  count(form_ref) as asset
from risk_register
where risk_category in ('fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1',
                        '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e')
and system_type = 'AR'
group by rollup(risk_category)
order by grouping(risk_category), risk_category;
```

or even

```
select nvl(risk_category, 'Total') as softfield,
  count(form_ref) as asset
...
```

Comment: @Nick - that gets the 1 and 2 in reverse order with the category values in the question, but no idea if that matters to the OP, so if it doesn't then not repeating the values makes sense. (Can make it `desc` of course, but depends what rules they need to use. A collection of values might make it simpler too. They might actually want the actual category keys, even...)

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. I using all those 4 example given. The output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cte with `WITH` , then  use your query twice :

```
With cte as (
  SELECT 1 AS SoftField, 
  count(form_ref) as Asset
  from risk_register 
  where risk_category = 'fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1' and system_type = 'AR'
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS SoftField,
  count(form_ref)as Operational
  from risk_register 
  where risk_category = '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e' and system_type = 'AR'
)
select * from cte
union all
select 'TOTAL', sum(asset) 
from cte
```

An alternative select use `ROLLUP`

```
select nvl(SoftField,'TOTAL') SoftField,
       sum(asset) Asset
from cte
group by rollup(SoftField)
```