# Oracle How to total up two select statement from different table

Tags: oracle, sum, union

I have this 2 select statement which is I'm using `union`.

```
select 'XYZ' as softfield,
  count(form_ref) as asset
from risk_register
where risk_category in ('fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1',
                        '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e')
and system_type = 'AR'
UNION 
select 'ABC' as softfield,
count(asset_no) from assets where status = 'A' and plant_type not like 'CST%'
```

the result is:

```
Softfield Asset
========= =====
ABC       7763
XYZ       146
```

what I'm trying to do now, i need to total up both select statement, to be like this:

```
Softfield Asset
 ========= =====
 ABC       7763
 XYZ       146
 Total     7909
```

Comment: Just try and slightly modify this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51241362/7998591

Answer (score 0):

I try this. its working.

```
 select 'XYZ' as softfield,
      count(form_ref) as asset
    from risk_register
    where risk_category in ('fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1',
                            '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e')
    and system_type = 'AR'

    UNION ALL

    select 'ABC' as softfield,
    count(asset_no) as asset from assets where status = 'A' and plant_type not like 'CST%'

    UNION ALL

    select 'Total' as Softfield,
    sum(asset)
    from
    ( select 'XYZ' as softfield,
      count(form_ref) as asset
    from risk_register
    where risk_category in ('fdbb8c65-cb78-4e9b-bfb7-d96a9d0b01b1',
                            '42a476db-0b3d-4375-9eba-5051d3a2507e')
    and system_type = 'AR'
    UNION ALL
    select 'ABC' as softfield,
    count(asset_no) as asset from assets where status = 'A' and plant_type not like 'CST%')
```